How to control access to Cellular data on iPhone?
I would like to control how my child uses cellular data on their iPhone.
Since Screen Time doesn't work properly, I am looking at Apple's Mobile Device Management (MDM).
The first idea was to enable the forceWiFiPowerOn option. However, this requires supervising the iPhone, which necessitates deleting all data on the device.
Is there another way to achieve what I need?
